# Solution to system of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a specific question regarding how the author of [this paper](http://v.web.umkc.edu/vaidyan/OR2008.pdf)

obtained the following solution for the system of nonlinear DEs.

**The system of nonlinear differential equations is:** $$
\frac{d{X_{SS}}}{dt}=\Lambda-\beta_IX_{IS}\frac{X_{SS}}{N}-\beta_AX_{AS}\frac{X_{SS}}{N}-\mu X_{SS} \\ \frac{d{X_{IS}}}{dt}=\beta_IX_{IS}\frac{X_{SS}}{N}+\beta_AX_{AS}\frac{X_{SS}}{N}-(\nu_{IS}+\mu)X_{IS} \\ \frac{d{X_{AS}}}{dt}=\nu_{IS}X_{IS}-(\mu+\mu_A)X_{AS} \\ N=X_{SS}+X_{IS}+X_{AS}$$

**The solution is:** $$X_{SS}=\frac{\Lambda(\nu_{IS}+\mu+\mu_A)}{\beta_I(\mu_A+\mu)+\nu_{IS}(\beta_A-\mu_A)} \\ X_{IS}=\frac{\Lambda(\mu+\mu_A)(R_0^H-1)}{\beta_I(\mu_A+\mu)+\nu_{IS}(\beta_A-\mu_A)} \\ X_{AS}=\frac{\Lambda\nu_{IS}(R_0^H-1)}{{\beta_I(\mu_A+\mu)+\nu_{IS}(\beta_A-\mu_A)}}$$

where $$R_0^H=\frac{\beta_I(\mu+\mu_A)+\beta_A\nu_{IS}}{(\nu_{IS}+\mu)(\mu+\mu_A)}$$

$X_{SS},X_{IS},X_{AS}$ are functions of $t$.

I tried everything - by hand, Maple, Mathematica, MATLAB - with no success. I tried in vain to add the equations and using integrating factors...

Comment: It's hard to understand the question without spending a lot of time studying the paper in details. Can you reformulate the question to extract the "minimal mathematical model" of what you don't understand?

Comment: @Peter Franek. OK all done. Please see edit.

Comment: What are the functions of $t$ here?

Comment: @BennettGardiner See edit.

Comment: Then aren't all the given solutions simply constants?